Why were the Israelites deprived of eating meat when they had their own cattle and sheep in the desert?
When the Israelites left Egypt they were allowed to take their flocks and herds with them (Ex 12:32).  They needed them for their sacrificial offerings - but they could only use those who were immaculate - so why did they reminisce longingly about eating pots of meat in Egypt (Ex 16:3) and then the LORD sent quail?
And again in (Num 11:4) more of the grumbling about wanting to eat meat and this time an over abundance of quail is given.  I can find no prohibition of eating their own animal’s meat; nor that all herds and flock were only to be used for their sacrifices to the LORD.  As they were all shepherds in Egypt presumably they all owned livestock?  Equally, with their cattle, there would have been enough leather to make many shoes when their old ones wore out; and yet the LORD performed the miracle that their shoes never wore out - implying that they had no way of replenishing them if they did.
Curious what answers you may be able to provide and very ready to admit I may have missed a passage that clears up this query!

Does this answer your question? Couldn't the Jews eat their livestock in addition to eating the manna in the Exodus period?

Welcome to the group Amanda. It's a good question but it's also a duplicate and will be closed shortly. It's a good practice to use the search bar to see if your question has already been addressed before writing it up to avoid wasted research and writing effort. (sorry if you tried this... I know from experience that this can happen!)

Let me add a bit to a previous answer along these lines:
What are some possibilities? [1]

The Israelites were tired of eating the same things time and time again. They were simply complaining because they wanted variety rather than because they had absolutely no meat.
In ancient Egypt, people worshiped various animals, including cattle. After leaving Egypt, the Israelites also started worshiping a golden calf made by Aaron while Moses was away (Exodus 32:1–4). It's possible that they may have been influenced by Egyptian beliefs to the point where they couldn't consume animals they considered sacred.
They planned to sell their livestock later and therefore they didn't want to eat them.
The Israelites had limited or nearly exhausted their supply of livestock during  their prolonged wilderness journey.


Rabbi Avraham Ibn Ezra suggests that they had already eaten a large
portion of their cattle. A this point, if they would all go to
purchase more meat at once, the price would skyrocket beyond their
means. [2]


Killing a large animal affords a person an abundance of food at one time. After that, since they didn't port refrigerators around in the wilderness, it had to be salted and eaten cold. The Israelites wanted smaller animals so they could enjoy fresh meat on demand. [2]

It's likely that they used some of their livestock for sacrifices and perhaps provisions. This could lead to a decrease in their herds and flocks over time. If we want to account for all variables we should also include natural factors such as disease and predators which could have decreased the size and influenced the health of their livestock.

Great question. I read the book of Jubilee's a few years back and was struck by this as well. The bottom line was god wanted them completely dependant on him.
In the Jubilee's book god allows those that ask to eat but kills 12,000 of them after for disobedience. Remembering that each tribe of Israel has 12,000. This theme is played out again in judas's fate as one of the twelve disciples fails in faith or obedience to God's will.

This question has, very much a rational answer.
The answer is written in Exodus 13:2. That’s the entire answer but the verse must be thought about in a modern cause and effect relationship. The LORD gave a commandment that deprived the Israelites of meat so that the Israelites had to rely on the LORD for food.
The Lord said to Moses, 2 “Consecrate to me every firstborn male. The first offspring of every womb among the Israelites belongs to me, whether human or animal.”
This commandment given to the Israelites at the time deprived the Israelites of having a bountiful source of meat. Since the firstborn of the animals were to be consecrated for the LORD, the option for meat would mostly be the elderly animals. That the firstborn cannot be eaten becomes an impossible scenario trying to keep the flocks of animals not only fed and watered from the natural resources available in the desert but also from complete extermination. The firstborn animals also cannot become parents in the future.
